# Persisting USB permission after reboot without replugging device

Tags: android, android-usb

In an Android app, I need permission for a specific USB device (known vendor/product ID), which is permanently plugged on the Android device.

So far I've made the following observations:

- when using [UsbManager.requestPermission()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html#requestPermission(android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) the permission is dismissed when replugging/rebooting and the popup's checkbox seems to have no effect at all on this behavior
- when [using intent filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host#using-intents), the permission is properly re-granted when replugging the USB device (even when replugging after a reboot, if the popup's checkbox was checked) **BUT the permission is not re-granted after reboot unless I unplug & replug the USB device**.

Is it possible to make sure that the permission popup is displayed only once ? (especially in the scenario when the Android device is rebooted and the USB device remains plugged in)

NB: the app isn't installed in the system folder and therefore cannot use the MANAGE_USB permission.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution is to use intent filters and add the `android:directBootAware="true"` attribute on the associated activity so that the `USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` event is correctly received after boot.

Comment: If I just could give you one MILLION up votes :-) Thank you very much. How did you arrive at that piece of code `android:directBootAware="true"`? Magic. I spent hours looking for this.

Comment: I gave up months ago trying to find a solution for this. By mere chance I re-searched about the topic and found your updated solution that works!

Comment: It seems the issue was fixed on Android 13, it works without `directBootAware`, but we still need to use intent filters if the permission allowance persist needed.

Answer (score 0):

***Persisting USB Permission is not possible,*** as the reboot option is stopping everything forcefully generally it makes the USB also unplugged.

There is one possibility to ask for replugging USB on reboot.

*Is it possible to make sure that the permission popup is displayed only once?* **No**

Because If your are connecting the usb which makes a deadlock situation for taking care of that they make it unplugged, rather than disturbing the system.

So it is not possible to make it USB Plugged-in.

Comment: We can't really say that the reboot "makes the USB unplugged" since the USB device is actually visible with UsbManager after reboot. It just doesn't keep (or re-grant) the access permission.

Comment: Yes, It removes the access which has given to the USB

Comment: do you know any way to programmatically trigger a unplug/replug ?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, and I ultimately left it to the Android manufacturer to solve.